# HTML textbox default value update with every input

Tags: html, textarea

I have this simple Html code here.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Text Box:<input type="text" name="host" value="default value" size=30 onchange="updateTextBox()" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update value in text box to current value"/>
</form>
```

Every time I click the button, I want the default value of the textbox to be updated to the value I most recently entered.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    /* give a name to the form and write it where "form_name" is */
    var newText = document.forms["form_name"]["host"].value;

    /* add this chunk in the submit button (onclick = "changeText()") */
    function changeText()
    {
        /* give an id to the text box input tag and replace "input_id" with that */
        document.getElementById("input_id").value = newText; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you make me an example ? it doesnt seem to work...

<html>
<script>
 var newText = document.forms["mainform"]["input"].value;
   
    function changeText()
    {
         document.getElementById("input1").value = newText; 
    }
</script>
<form name="mainform" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" onclick ="changeText()" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<html>

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick ="changeText(event)" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />

changeText(e)
{
   event.preventDefault();
   //functionality here
   $('form').submit();
}